# Partial Objects In Oracle

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I was using flat stored procedures (flat means not contained in objects) in oracle to update my tables. For example I have a table Person with columns Id, FirstName, LastName, Address, Salary. I made a flat procedure Person_UpdFirstName and this procedure has two parameters: Id, FirstName. Inside the procedure, I find the row in the Person table that matches with the parameter Id and update the FirstName with the parameter FirstName. Usual stuff, nothing new.

Now, I am using oracle objects. I have an object PersonType, this is a udt. This object has same fields as columns in the table Person. I have put all of the procedures related to the Person table inside the PersonType object, that is, instead of using flat procedures I start using member procedures. None of the member procedures has any parameter, they take values from the fields of the object. For example, in the case of Person_UpdFirstName flat procedure, now I have a member procedure UpdFirstName. This member procedure do not take any parameter, it uses the Id and FirstName fields of the object itself, and update the Person table as before.

The problem is, when I was using flat procedures, I was passing parameters such as Id, FirstName, so in a large system with hundreds of tables, I cannot make a mistake in passing parameters to the stored procedure because number and type of parameters in each stored procedure is fixed. Now that I am using objects, I have to remember what fields of the object to be filled, there is no built in check in the system. This is fine as long as the fields in the table Person are non-nullable because it would throw an exception anyways but if the fields in the table are nullable, or when I am comparing values, then I can have lots of logical errors.

My question is, is there some built-in way to close this door of potential errors. I have some rough solutions but not sure:

1. Some kind of partial objects. My member methods should be forced to take in parameter those partial objects. For example I have a partial object PersonUpdFirstNameType, this has only one field FirstName and then my UpdFirstName member method take this as a parameter. Ofcourse its cumbersome to make a separate partial-type for each operation on a table. I don't really like this solution
2. I don't pass objects from c# to oracle procedures, instead I pass variables in parameters and then manually build (or not build) oracle objects as needed.

I have found out a way to map oracle objects with c# classes. For this, I don't have to use any ORM tool. I just have to add up a few attributes on c# classes and c# fields of those classes and implement a few interfaces. So, I can actually pass c# objects to oracle procedures and use "." syntax in oracle procedures to access the fields which contains the actual data.

I think the problem I am asking is a general oop problem, so its not specific to any particular language. The general problem, is suppose you have a class C with fields F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 and methods M1, M2, M3. M1 do some operation on some of the fields, M2 do some operation on some other fields, M3 do some operations on some fields which may also be acted upon by M1 or M2. A client code is making objects of C and can fill any number (including zero) of the parameters before calling any method. What if the client code call a method before putting values in the fields required by the method. In C#, I think this is handled by compiler by throwing exceptions if you not initialize the fields first; you can also leave the fields empty in definition of class such as "int i" without putting any value in i so that if a method is called now compiler throw an exception. There is no such support in dbms because of the nullable fields. If lets say you are comparing Id of a table-row against Id of an object-field and you forgot to put any value in the object-field then the table-row's id is compared against null and no row is matched and therefore no update happens (suppose you want to update rows which match the id, usual update operation).

I just want to know if there is some built-in check in the system to handle such cases.

Comment: Why can't you initiate your objects with constructors ? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i16312 this will allow you to be sure that all attributes are initialized before calling the methods

Comment: @Cade: I want to pass the objects from c#.

Comment: @Cade:Even when using constructors, it may be that I must initialize fields F1, F2 for M1; fields F1, F4 for M2; so i make two separate constructors and then first call them, then call the M1/M2. Still I have to remember which constructor to call before calling which method, no built-in check. The whole point of post is to find some built-in check like in the case of flat procedures.

Comment: I probably don't really understand what you're looking for: a- do you want to get some errors in the DB or in C# compliation ? b- even in c#, when you call a method that uses an un-initiated attribute, you won't get an error in compilation (you can have another method (that is never called) that assignes a value to the attribute )

Comment: @Cade: I want to get error in db when calling stored procedure that expects a field of object that is yet not initialized. The real killer is the nullability. In an object fields are automatically initialized to null at time of object creation. Then how can I know that either the field is null because it is intended to be null or its null because I forgot to put value in it.

Comment: I don't understand why you say it's the `nullability`. In c# for example, if you have a method that uses an attribute which wasn't initiated you'll get an exception in **runtime** not **compilation** time! if you want to get exceptions in runtime then you can add a check in your member method and raise an exception if one of the fields is null

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea how to have an Error in **compilation time**, and I don't know of any other OO language that gives such a feature either (how can the compiler tell when or where the attribute was initiated ?)
What you can do is have Exceptions in **runtime** (somewhat like `NullPointerException` or `ArgumentNullException`).
For example:

```
create or replace type person_o as object
(
  id    number,
  fname varchar2(32),
  lname varchar2(32),

  member procedure update_lname
);
/

create or replace type body person_o is

  member procedure update_lname is
  begin
    if self.lname is null then
      Raise_application_error(-20000, 'null attribute');
    end if;

    update persons_table set last_name = self.lname where id = self.id;
    commit;
  end;

end;
/
```